# Bounded linear mappings in Hilbert space preserve orthogonality?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

My question is the title of this thread!

Assume we have a bounded, linear mapping $A:H\to H$ where $(H,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$
is a Hilbert space, and two non-zero elements that are orthogonal, $\langle\Bbb u,\Bbb v\rangle=0$. Is it then true that also $\langle A(\Bbb u),A(\Bbb v)\rangle =0$ ?

If so, how can I prove this?

Comment: No, this is not true even in two-dimensional space. Consider projections, for instance.

Comment: Yes, but is a linear mapping the same as a linear transform? A projection would be a mapping like $A:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^2$. In this case I was considering linear mappings that would be like $A:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{R}^2 \ni (x,y) \mapsto (x,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Preserving orthogonality is an extremely strong condition for an arbitrary mapping to have. Even most very nice mappings that fail this condition: for example, left-multiplication on column vectors by $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is a bijective, Hermetian, bounded, linear (and continuous) mapping in finite-dimensional real space, but notice:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
while using the standard inner product shows $\left\langle\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right\rangle = 2+2\neq 0$.

(However, it is also a very desirable property for a mapping to have, so it probably has a name: A *unitary* matrix will preserve all inner products; you can probably weaken this condition if you only care about the orthogonals.)

Comment: Good example! Thank you!

Comment: Positive semidefinite matrices don't in general preserve inner products. _Unitary_ matrices do. And to preserve orthogonality, real multiples of unitary matrices are the ones.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you!