# Properties of ON-basis in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with an ON-basis $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and let $A$ be a bounded linear mapping $A:H\to H$ such that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\|A(e_n)\|^2<\infty$$

1: Show that if $(f_m)_{m=1}^\infty$ is another ON-basis for $H$, then

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\|A(e_n)\|^2=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\|A(f_m)\|^2$$

2: Also show that

$$\|A\|\leq(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\|A(e_n)\|^2)^{1/2}$$

As for 1), I started with $\sum_{m=1}^\infty\|A(f_m)\|^2=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\langle A(f_m),A(f_m)\rangle$ and since $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is an ON-basis, it can be written as

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left\langle A(\sum_{n_1=1}^\infty\langle f_m,e_{n_1}\rangle e_{n_1}),A(\sum_{n_1=1}^\infty\langle f_m,e_{n_2}\rangle e_{n_2})\right\rangle=$$

$$\sum_{n_1=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n_2=1}^\infty\langle f_m,e_{n_1}\rangle\langle e_{n_2},f_m\rangle\langle A(e_{n_1}),A(e_{n_2})\rangle\right)=$$

Now, the summations within the large paranthesis may also be written as

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{\overset{n_2=1,}{n_2\ne n_1}}^\infty\langle f_m,e_{n_1}\rangle\langle e_{n_2},f_m\rangle\langle A(e_{n_1}),A(e_{n_2})\rangle + \sum_{\overset{m=1}{n_2=n_1}}^\infty\langle f_m,e_{n_1}\rangle\langle e_{n_2},f_m\rangle\langle A(e_{n_1}),A(e_{n_2})\rangle  $$

...and the summation on the right can now be written as $\|A(e_{n_1})\|^2\cdot\sum_{m=1}^\infty|\langle f_m,e_{n_1}\rangle|^2$. By Parseval's identity, $\sum_{m=1}^\infty|\langle f_m,e_{n_1}\rangle|^2=\|e_{n_1}\|^2$ if $(f_m)_{m=1}^\infty$ is an ON-basis, which it was by assumption. So far so good. The problem is that I got a remainder above, the double-summation when $n_2\neq n_1$, which should be zero. I tried some different $A$'s to see if it holds, and it seems it does. My first attempt in solving this was actually the (false) hypothesis that if two elements are orthogonal, then so are the linear mapping of them. I asked this yesterday:

[Bounded linear mappings in Hilbert space preserve orthogonality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522705/bounded-linear-mappings-in-hilbert-space-preserve-orthogonality)

Maybe I messed this all up more than necessary. If there's an easier way to show 1), I'd be happy, but anyways it would also be nice with some argument to why that "double-summation" above equals zero, or if I'm just biased in picking arbitrary $A$'s.

As for 2), I pretty much end up with the same problem as with 1).

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use Parseval in the first step itself!

1.
$$
\sum_n \|T(e_n)\|^2 = \sum_n \sum_m |\langle T(e_n), f_m\rangle|
$$
$$
= \sum_n \sum_m |\langle e_n, T^{\ast}(f_m)\rangle | = \sum_m \sum_n |\langle e_n, T^{\ast}(f_m)\rangle |
$$
$$
= \sum_m \|T^{\ast}(f_m)\|^2 = \sum_m \|T(f_m)\|^2
$$
2. For $x\in H$ with $\|x\| = 1$, write $x = \sum_n \alpha_n e_n$, with $\|\alpha\|^2 = \sum_n |\alpha_n|^2 = 1$, then
$$
\|T\|^2 = \sup_{\|\alpha\| = 1} \sum_n \sum_m \sum_k \alpha_n\overline{\alpha_m}\overline{\langle T(e_m), e_k\rangle} \langle T(e_n), e_k\rangle 
$$
By Cauchy Schwarz,
$$
\|T\|^2 \leq \sum_n\sum_k |\langle T(e_n), e_k\rangle |^2 = \sum_n \|T(e_n)\|^2
$$
This gives you what you want.

Comment: Very nice! Using Parserval's identity right at the beginning never occurred to me. Very nice indeed!